# Tomcat 403 Error

Tags: java, tomcat, admin

Here's my `tomcat-users.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="role1"/>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <role rolename="manager"/>

    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
    <user username="MyAdmin" password="pswd" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I restart tomcat and go to `localhost:8080/manager`. It asks me to log in. I enter the admin/manager credentials (u = MyAdmin and p = pswd) and it fails, giving me the following 403:

[image]

Whats going on here? I'm almost 100% sure I have the XML configured right!?! Is it possible something else isn't configured properly?

Comment: have you tried adding a user with just manager rights?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark. Please try having MyAdmin as the first user in your file.

Comment: Don't mind trying that but why do you think that would change anything (can you point me to some docs)? Just curious.

Comment: Did you changethe MemoryRealm in server.xml?

Comment: I don't even *see* a `<MemoryRealm>` element in my `server.xml`...

Comment: Please note that if this is related to your other post (an RFP that includes deploying a bean to an app container) that Tomcat is not an app container--if this is for something else, disregard this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized from your screenshot you are using Tomcat 7.
Roles have changed a little bit. See the updated [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)

> You can find the role names in the web.xml file of the Manager web
>   application. The available roles are:
>
> manager-gui — Access to the HTML interface.
>
> manager-status — Access to the "Server Status" page only.
>
> manager-script — Access to the tools-friendly plain text interface that is described in >this document, and to the "Server Status" page.
>
> manager-jmx — Access to JMX proxy interface and to the "Server Status" page.

update your role to the appropriate setting.

Answer (score -4):

Those roles are gone. Your account needs the `manager-gui` role. You obviously did not read the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access).