# Why Tomcat gives 403 error?

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, access-control

I configure my tomcat-users.xml below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<tomcat-users> 
<role rolename="tomcat"/> 
<role rolename="role1"/> 
<role rolename="manager"/> 
<role rolename="admin"/> 
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/> 
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/> 
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/> 
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>  
</tomcat-users>
```

I placed an html page under `webapps/dupload/task.html` page which submit a query form to a servlet. The html code is following:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <TITLE>A Sample Form Using POST</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="#FDF5E6">
<H2 ALIGN="CENTER">SimpleTaskQuery</H2>

<FORM ACTION="http://10.5.20.78:8080/mps4/ui/SimpleTaskQueryServlet"
   METHOD="POST">
 <CENTER>
Task Id:
 <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="id" VALUE="111"><BR>
 <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT">
 </CENTER>
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But when I submit the form, tomcat gives the following error:

```
HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied

type Status report

message Access to the requested resource has been denied

description Access to the specified resource (Access to the requested resource has been denied) has been forbidden.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.26
```

I have already edited the tomcat-users.xml and login with the admin user account. Why does this still not work?

**Update:**

The webapp's web.xml is following:
web.xml:

```
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>HTMLManger and Manager command</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/ui/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>viewer</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Tomcat Manager Application</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <description> </description>
    <role-name>viewer</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

Ｉ　ｅｄｉｔ　ｔｈｅ　ｔｏｍｃａｔ－ｕｓｅｒｓ．ｘｍｌ　ｔｏ：

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="viewer"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="viewer" password="viewer" roles="admin,tomcat,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Ｂｕｔ　ｉｔ　ｓｔｉｌｌ　ｎｏｔ　ｗｏｒｋ．

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648212/tomcat-403-error)

Comment: Please post your web.xml

Comment: Is your app called "dupload" or "mps4"?

Comment: My app called mps4. "dupload" have a html form to submit to the mps4 app to get task status.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix this:

```
<user username="viewer" password="viewer" roles="admin,tomcat,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

This user needs the role 'manager-script' to be deleted so that he will gain the access via html-interface. So it should look like:

```
<user username="viewer" password="viewer" roles="admin,tomcat,manager-gui"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your web.xml says the role 'viewer' is required. You log in as the admin user, who does not have that role.

Update your tomcat-users.xml as follows:

```
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui, viewer"/>;
```

Oddly enough, your 'viewer' user doesn't have the viewer role either, but that's not what causes the problem (if you log in as admin)